# ROC for more than 2 outcome categories

Tags: r, data-mining, roc, rocr

How do you construct ROC Curves when there are more than two outcome categories (in my case, I have four)?  I've heard you should do this for the most popular group. Are there any other ideas? Are there functions in R to help with this?

Comment: Do you mean how to construct ROC's when there are +2 **models**?

Comment: Or do you mean that there are 4 outcome categories?

Comment: Categories :) I edited my post

Comment: I would suggest checking out this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38541/creating-roc-curve-for-multi-level-logistic-regression-model-in-r

Comment: What about ROC curves makes them insightful to you?  Are you really interested in concordance probabilities ($c$-index; ROC area; pure discrimination measure)?  I find the ROC area to be helpful even though the curves are not helpful to me.  And you can generalize the idea of concordance probability to multiple categories using Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation coefficient.

Comment: Nice one @FrankHarrell . ROC Curves are a great way to visualize how good are your classifiers if you put many of them on 1 plot :)

Comment: How does that give you any insight?

Comment: The Higher the Curve is, the better the classifier is

Comment: How does the area under the curve not capture that?

Comment: It does not capture the situation You chociaz the cut argument. Even the AUC is Higher from one Curve it does not mean there exists an argument from lover-auc Curve that Give Higher value of ROC Curve :p I think it's how's more than AUC. But it might be only my opinion.

Comment: I haven't seen an example yet where someone viewed an ROC curve and it led to an action that was both useful and correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several ideas and references are discussed in:

- [A simple generalization of the area under the ROC curve to multiple class classification problems](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=513543).
- [Multi-class ROC (a tutorial)](https://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/ICML04tutorial/ROCtutorialPartIII.pdf) (using "volumes" under ROC)

Other approaches include computing

- macro-average ROC curves (average per class in a 1-vs-all fashion)
- micro-averaged ROC curves (consider all positives and negatives together as  single class)

You can see [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc.html) in some libraries like scikit-learn.

See also this other thread in CrossValidated: 
[How to compute precision/recall for multiclass-multilabel classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification)

Comment: FYI - the link to the multi-class ROC tutorial doesn't work

Comment: @rocinante Fixed.

Comment: @Josh that's the vast and outstanding piece of literature :) Thank you very much. That was something I was looking for! CV is a great place.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ideas is to use one-vs-all classifier. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110550/49130) answer gives move information about it, including some R code.

Here's a plot from that answer

[image]

Comment: Very usefull comment. Thanks for that! Nice idea by the way.